# Why was my question marked as a duplicate when the limits are obviously different?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question has been marked as a duplicate despite extensive research and noting how my question *differs* from the questions I'd found.

[Does Capitalism and Democracy survive free energy and automation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55837/does-capitalism-and-democracy-survive-free-energy-and-automation)

I then edited further to explain how it *significantly* differs from [How would humans adapt if low-wage labor was done by robots?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51423/how-would-humans-adapt-if-low-wage-labor-was-done-by-robots) .

But the last vote came in to mark it as a duplicate.

Can people here not get past the title of a question when looking at duplicates? If that's the case should I put all the constraints in the title?

Is my question too broad and should I break it down step by step? But it wasn't closed as too broad.

### Edit: Two answers to two questions

Frostfyre claims that the accepted answers on the two questions actually answer my question.

The accepted answer to [How would humans adapt if low-wage labor was done by robots?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51423/how-would-humans-adapt-if-low-wage-labor-was-done-by-robots) talks about how humans and a democratic government in a capitalist system will move to higher-skill and knowledge work. My constraint #3 *states as a given* that low-skill people had moved to knowledge work, so there aren't any luddites left to complain about machines taking their jobs.

The accepted answer to [What's the most likely "post democracy" form of political government?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28980/whats-the-most-likely-post-democracy-form-of-political-government) provides brilliant commentary on oligarchy, plutocracy, scientocracy, technocracy, delegative democracy, direct democracy and even fictional government systems.

These are provided within a quasi-democratic worldview. But it provides no insight into the forces driving change as a result of almost-free energy and widespread automation.

Comment: Curious. My comment to you on that question seems to have been deleted. I voted to close as a duplicate because your question appeared to have been answered previously, between the first question you linked and the one yours was closed as a duplicate of. Neither perfectly answers your question, but combined they do.

Comment: @Frostfyre I saw your comment was missing. I don't think *I* deleted it. I find it strange that a question can be closed because two separate answers are deemed to cover the territory while they never cover the union of the two questions. By the same logic *every* answer on SE contains the entire alphabet and most words in the dictionary. Therefore every future question is answered already by every other answer.

Comment: That's a clearly flawed argument. I can write a legible sentence that has ever English letter in it, so it must be able to answer any English question. I don't think we've ever had a case before where the answer to one question was merely the sum of the accepted answer on two other questions.

Comment: Merely the sum? Try the intersection of two constraints. And if you look at the two accepted answers on the two questions, they do not answer the question

Comment: @paulzag You didn't delete it. It would have taken Frostfyre his/herself or a mod. *Possibly* a SE script that automatically cleans up things like spam.

Comment: @Frostfyre when a question is closed as a dupe, SE automatically deletes comments that proposed that dupe.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's great, but my comment wasn't the one that proposed the duplicate. I merely mentioned that the two linked questions combined answered the question. I guess the script that runs is rather smart...

Comment: @Frostfyre oh, sorry.  Looks like that was me; there was a flag on something else, and this meta post already existed, so I deleted obsolete comments and added a link to this question.